# Iterate through a treeview in VB6

Tags: vb6, treeview

I have a treeview control on the form which looks like:
[image]

I want to iterate the treeview and write the contents of the treeview to ini file. So the ini file for the given tree would look like:

```
[EnvironmentSystem]
UpdateRate=50.0
InclinationAngle=20.7
Latitude=34.0

[Reflection]
NumReflectionLevel=5
NumSunLightLevel=5
NumWeatherLevel=3
TextureNameFormat=Reflection%01d%01d%02d.tga

[CloudsClear]
MaxClouds=48
MaxCloudParticles=51
3DCloudMaterial=CloudMaterial
3DCloudHorizontalSize=1400.0
3DCloudVerticalSize=600.0
3DCloudSizeDeviation=0.6
3DCloudParticleDensity=2.4
ParticleSize=300.0
ParticleSizeDeviation=0.3
MinBaseAltitude=400.0
MaxBaseAltitude=2450.0
UseBottomRow=TRUE
```

Here is the code that I have written:

```
Private Sub TvSaveToIniBtn_Click()
    Dim nodx As Node
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sectionCount As Integer
    sectionCount = TreeView1.Nodes(1).Children
    Set nodx = TreeView1.Nodes(1).Child.FirstSibling
        For i = 1 To sectionCount
        SaveNodesToIni (nodx.Text)
        Set nodx = nodx.Next
    Next
End Sub


Sub SaveNodesToIni(sName As Variant)
Dim tvn As Node
Set tvn = TreeView1.Nodes(sName)
Dim chil As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim ret As Integer
Dim keyValuePair() As String
Dim nElements As Integer


chil = tvn.Children: If chil = 0 Then Exit Sub     ' if no children the exit
Set tvn = tvn.Child.FirstSibling
For a = 1 To chil
    keyValuePair = Split(tvn.Text, "=")
    nElements = UBound(keyValuePair) - LBound(keyValuePair) + 1
    If nElements > 0 Then
        ret = WritePrivateProfileString(sName, keyValuePair(0), keyValuePair(1), "C:\\MyPrograms\\config.ini")
    End If
    Set tvn = tvn.Next
Next
```

End Sub

It is not giving the correct output, it gets stuck at the second section of reflection and is not able to read the third one. Something wrong with the code.

Comment: You're passing the node text to the `SaveNodesToIni` method, then using that as the index to select the proper node from the tree. Are the node keys the same as the text?